# ConTeXt: Multiple colour stops for linear_shade

Tags: header-footer, context, metapost, shading, metafun

## Background

Looking to parameterize a horizontal rule (for headers and footers) that has three colour stops (A to B to C) and a variable thickness. For example:

[image: Thick rule]

[image: Thin rule]

## Single Stop Code

The following code draws lines in the document header and footer using `linear_shade`:

```
\setupcolors[pagecolormodel=auto]

% Colour Stop #1
\definecolor[BrandTertiaryColour][h=FF6A00]
% Colour Stop #2
\definecolor[BrandPrimaryColour][h=E61739]
% Colour Stop #3
\definecolor[BrandSecondaryColour][h=991F3D]

% Define the graphics for the header and footer separator line
\startMPinclusions
  % t is the line thickness (in points)
  def create_line( expr t ) =
    path pbegan;
    pbegan := envelope pensquare of ((0, 0) -- (OverlayWidth, 0)) yscaled t;

    linear_shade(
      pbegan, 0, \MPcolor{BrandTertiaryColour}, \MPcolor{BrandPrimaryColour}
    );
  enddef;
\stopMPinclusions

\startuseMPgraphic{HeaderSeparator}
  create_line( 2pt );
\stopuseMPgraphic

\startuseMPgraphic{FooterSeparator}
  create_line( 0.5pt );
\stopuseMPgraphic

\defineoverlay[HeaderSeparatorOverlay][
  \useMPgraphic{HeaderSeparator}
]

\defineoverlay[FooterSeparatorOverlay][
  \useMPgraphic{FooterSeparator}
]

% Draw the header and footer rules.
\setupbackgrounds[header][text][
  background=HeaderSeparatorOverlay,
]

\setupbackgrounds[footer][text][
  background=FooterSeparatorOverlay,
]

\starttext
  \input knuth
\stoptext
```

## Questions

I am wondering:

- Where do I find the prototype definition for `linear_shade` (i.e., does it support multiple colour stops)?
- How can the duplicate Overlays (HeaderSeparatorOverlay, FooterSeparatorOverlay) be eliminated?

## Ideas

I was thinking of two calls to `linear_shade`:

```
    path pbegan;
    path pended;
    pbegan := envelope pensquare of ((0, 0) -- ((OverlayWidth/2), 0)) yscaled t;
    pended := envelope pensquare of (((OverlayWidth/2), 0) -- (OverlayWidth, 0)) yscaled t;

    linear_shade(
      pbegan, 0, \MPcolor{BrandTertiaryColour}, \MPcolor{BrandPrimaryColour}
    );

    linear_shade(
      pended, 0, \MPcolor{BrandPrimaryColour}, \MPcolor{BrandSecondaryColour}
    );
```

But there's probably a way to write it with fewer lines of--or less brittle--code.

## Related

- [lost linear_shade output](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/160400/2148)
- [(ConTeXt MkIV) Text in PiechartMP](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/93922/2148)
- https://www.tug.org/docs/metapost/mpman.pdf
- http://www.ctex.org/documents/context/metafun-p.pdf
- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/330016/2148
- http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/useMPgraphic
- http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/startMPinclusions

Comment: [`\`kpsexpand '$TEXMFCONTEXT'\`/metapost/context/base/mpiv/mp-mlib.mpiv`](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/blob/52c5102fab837626fe9bb359b3eda6066e1a968e/metapost/context/base/mpiv/mp-mlib.mpiv#L875-L884)

Comment: So no formal Javadoc-like documentation for these functions, then, that describe the behaviour, inputs, and outputs.

Comment: Unfortunately not.  All documentation for the Metafun macros is in the Metafun manual, which can be quite incomplete at times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [Metafun manual](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/metafun-p.pdf) section 8.3 “Shading”, subsection 8.3.3 “The new method”.

Add as many `withshadestep` as you want.

```
% Colour Stop #1
\definecolor[BrandTertiaryColour][h=FF6A00]
% Colour Stop #2
\definecolor[BrandPrimaryColour][h=E61739]
% Colour Stop #3
\definecolor[BrandSecondaryColour][h=991F3D]

\startuseMPgraphic{Separator}
fill fullsquare xyscaled (OverlayWidth, OverlayLineWidth)
    withshademethod "linear"
    withshadevector (0,1)
    withshadestep (
        withshadefraction .5
        withshadecolors (\MPcolor{BrandTertiaryColour}, \MPcolor{BrandPrimaryColour})
    )
    withshadestep (
        withshadefraction 1
        withshadecolors (\MPcolor{BrandPrimaryColour}, \MPcolor{BrandSecondaryColour})
    )
\stopuseMPgraphic

\defineoverlay
  [SeparatorOverlay]
  [\useMPgraphic{Separator}]

% Draw the header and footer rules.
\setupbackgrounds
  [header][text]
  [background=SeparatorOverlay,
   rulethickness=2pt]

\setupbackgrounds
  [footer][text]
  [background=SeparatorOverlay,
   rulethickness=0.5pt]

\starttext
  \input knuth
\stoptext
```

[image]